# I want to use node.js to parse a remote log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to use node.js to follow a log file that is on a remote server. I used "sequest" to connect to the server. No problem there. It even allows me to run commands, but when I try "tail -f" it fails doesn't return anything. Removing the -f works, I asume it is because there command is not "done" so there is nothing to return yet? Am I missing something? Is there another alternative to get the output of a 'tail -f' command on a remote location?

```
var sequest = require('sequest');
var conf = require('./config/properties.js');



var prop = conf.ssh.dev;

var seq = sequest.connect(prop.host,{password:prop.password});

seq('tail -f -n 100 /interwoven/LiveSiteDisplayServices/runtime/tomcat/logs/catalina.out', function (e, stdout) {
        console.log(stdout.split('\n')); 
});
```

Comment: You might be right. What exactly is the question?

Comment: I need to know how can I get the output of a tail -f command.

Comment: Try piping. Examples on the npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequest

Comment: Had tried piping before, but this time I added a little faith. It worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Adrian Lynch recommendation I used piping specified in the sequest documentation at [npmjs.com/package/sequest](http://npmjs.com/package/sequest). It ended up looking something like this:

```
var sequest = require('sequest');
var conf = require('./config/properties.js');



var prop = conf.ssh.dev;

var seq = sequest(prop.host, { password: prop.password});
seq.pipe(process.stdout);
seq.write('tail -f -n 100 /interwoven/LiveSiteDisplayServices/runtime/tomcat/logs/catalina.out');
```